# networkx nodes' degre - unhashable types

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I'm using `networkx`, I created a graph using `nx.gridgraph` and now I need to have a list of my nodes ordered by their own degree (so to divide the surface ones from the others). I tried to use the code here, where A is a `nx.grid_graph(dim=[N,N,N])` so its nodes have coordinates like (1,2,3)

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

N = 4
A = nx.grid_graph(dim=[N,N,N])

k = np.asarray(list(map(itemgetter(1), nx.degree(A))))
node_out = np.asarray(A.node[np.where(k <= 4.)[0]])
```

but this gives me the error:

> File "", line 9, in 
>       node_out = np.asarray(A.node[np.where(k <= 4.)[0]])
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/classes/reportviews.py",
>   line 178, in **getitem**
>       return self._nodes[n]
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

could someone help me? Thank you

Comment: What do you want `node_out = np.asarray(A.node[np.where(k <= 4.)[0]])` to do?

Comment: A.node apparently is a dictionary.  The where expression creates an array.

Comment: Thank you all for your help